# Proving the first Bianchi identity only from the other three Riemann curvature tensor identities

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, tensor-calculus, curvature

Given that $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$, $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$ and $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ can I prove that $R_{abcd}+R_{acdb}+R_{adbc}=0$ without using the definition of the Riemann curvature tensor? Are the above identities sufficient?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025665/11127

Comment: I'm voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.